# Валидация в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь вызывать исключения для не валидных значений предполагая, что они будут обработаны в соответствии с ExceptionValidationRule, однако ничего не происходит и приложение просто падает с созданным мной исключением.

```
    public string code
    {
        get
        {
            return _project.code;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_project.code != value)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    throw new ArgumentException("code is empty");
                else
                {
                    _project.code = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("code");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    <TextBox Text="{Binding code, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: не понятно: падает при запуске? вы ловите эту ошибку, когда присваиваете значение? или речь о том, что окно запустилось, а при вводе пустого значения - падает? На последнее не похоже (не должно быть), а первое вероятно - создавая модель для связывания и присваивая null, вы вызываете необработанное исключение рушит приложение. до binding'а даже дело не доходит.

Comment: Именно когда присваивается пустое значение, когда фокус покидает поле текстовое поле.

Comment: А вы точно уверены, что приложение падает? Попробуйте запустить без Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы приложение не падало в Debug режиме надо вырубить галочку у  `User-unhandled` у `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` в листе Exceptions по пути Debug-> Exception -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Или можно запускать приложение в Release версии.